# I need to annotate advent of Covid 19 (12-01-2020) in the graph using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

i have been trying to annotate advent of covid (12-01-2020) in the graph using Matplotlib for the past 4 days yet unsuccessful. Iam reaching the deadline for my college seminar presentation.

csv file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14aQErbks2lAu1nnEtPUrdY-2xCi8XSrz/view?usp=sharing

What i need:

1. x axis should be in years
2. plot the vertical line on the particular date (12-01-2020)
3. Annotate "Covid Breakout"

Note: When i try plot the graph in the x axis in years, i can't specify vlines and annotate values because there is no value to quote between 2020 and 2021.

Thank you...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Loading the data form the disk
read = pd.read_csv("Graph.csv", parse_dates=['date'],
                            index_col=['date'])

# Plotting the graph with custom properties
plt.plot(read.index.values,
    read['Blockchain'],
    color='purple',
     label = "Carriage Services, Inc.")
# Annotate advent of covid in US
plt.annotate("Covid", xy=("12-01-2020", 20))
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The fix is that there is no `12-01` in the data and the x-axis specification must be in timestamp format.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

read = pd.read_csv('./data/Graph_20201225.csv', sep=',', parse_dates=\['date'\],index_col=\['date'\])
read.index = pd.to_datetime(read.index, format='%Y-%m-%d')
plt.plot(read.index.values,
    read\['Blockchain'\],
    color='purple',
     label = "Carriage Services, Inc.")
# Annotate advent of covid in US
plt.annotate("Covid", xy=(pd.Timestamp('2020-12-06 00:00:00'), 20))
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]